# Can't override styles set in nth-child

Tags: html, css

So, I've stumbled upon a strange CSS behaviour trying to override nth-child

Consider the following example

```css
li:nth-child(2n+1){
    color: red;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.hmm{
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="hmm">HMM</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li class="hmm">HMM</li>
    <li class="hmm">HMM</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

The question is, why doesn't `.hmm{...}` declaration override the `li:nth-child` declaration?

I.e., why wouldn't all HMMs become bold green? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it just comes down to specificity.  If you look at the styles in the developer tools in your browser, the `.hmm` styles are being overridden by `li:nth-child(2n+1)` https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ has a good explanation of the different levels of specificity. I believe both your class and tag+child selector both fall under class 3 which is why it's not super clear what comes first.

Comment: Your first selector is `011` and the second one is `010` in specificity so the first one is stronger due to the `tag` name https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: That's curious, I wonder how I could have missed that "specificity" thing, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because of  [Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Like more general rules will be overridden by more specific rules. `li:nth-child` is more specific than `.hmm`. So just increase the specificity of `.hmm` by adding `li.hmm`

```css
li:nth-child(2n+1){
  color: red;
  font-weight:normal;
}

li.hmm{
  color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="hmm">HMM</li>
<li>test</li>
<li class="hmm">HMM</li>
<li class="hmm">HMM</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**Update:**

Order of importance, highest 1 to lowest 4.

1. `<div style='...'></div>`: Style applied here is the most important.
2. `id`: Because `id` is supposed to unique in a page.
3. `class`: There can be multiple classes so they have lower importance than `id`. `pseudo-classes` and `attributes` also comes here.
4. `element`: Least.

Example:

`<li style='...'></li>` > `#thatListElement` > `li.myClass` > `.myClass` > `li`

Answer (score 1):

Type selectors (e.g., `h1`) and pseudo-elements (e.g., `::before`) are the first ones in the order.

After them you have class selectors (e.g., `.example`), attributes selectors (e.g., `[type="radio"]`)

Some useful link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Since the CSS rule has specificity. Means the precedence rule. The element and class have different specificity. Element and pseudo-elements have higher priority so its css rules have precedence over classes. My solution is

```
   <style>

    li:nth-child(2n + 1){
     font-weight:normal;
     color : red;
    }

    li.hmm{
      color:green !important ;
      font-weight:bold !important;
    }
  </style>

<ul>
      <li class="hmm">HMM</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li class="hmm">HMM</li>
      <li class="hmm">HMM</li>
      <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

You can read about specificity here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity